# Problem getting notifications of direct messages in Twitter

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, twitter

For the past few days, I have not been getting notifications when I receive a direct message on my Twitter account. **I keep changing the notification settings to the way that I want them, but they keep resetting back to default.** I have tried uninstalling the app and reinstalling it.  I have tried installing the app from the App store and from the Settings menu on my iPhone 4.

Any help to the situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be better off emailing Twitter: https://support.twitter.com

Comment: try your "other" twitter account!

Comment: Let us know if you have additional data, but this looks more like an isolated failure where we need to guess what you've done to troubleshoot this...